# Ubuntu won't boot when choose "Try Ubuntu without installing"

Tags: 14.04, boot, uefi, ssd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 to my PC's HDD which has ASROCK's UEFI and windows10 already installed on an SSD.

I know there are some problems with installing Linux distributions on UEFI machines but I heard that Ubuntu won't have any issues.

But when I insert my UnetBootin usb and select it to boot and choose "try Ubuntu without installing", it won't continue and my display turns black.

Here are some pictures.

[image]

After choosing "Try Ubuntu without installing", it displays nothing but a little light black. I found if I type "Ctrl + alt + Insert" or "Ctrl + alt + Delete" the display becomes darker.

I successfully installed win10 and Ubuntu separately in SSD and HDD on another PC which is not UEFI. But I don't know what should I try to solve this problem

Comment: This might be related to you're graphics adapter. What is it?

Comment: Graphics adapter, I think you mean GPU, is GTX1080. Here is the pic of GPU-Z http://imgur.com/sCiF409

Comment: Not sure about that, but I would guess the nouveau driver embedded with the ubuntu installer has no support for the 1080. and as the propriatary drivers of nvidia are not on the discs, the graphics setup might fail.

Comment: UnetBootin can be problematic. There are plenty of similar questions here related to that software. I suggest you to try with another one (the official guide recommends Rufus USB). Check this out: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: perhaps give ubuntu 16.04 a try as the drivers are a aproximately 2 years younger there.

Comment: I agree with Phillip-Zyan. The GTX 1080 is still fairly new, so your best bet, if this is a graphics issue, is to give 16.04 a go.

Answer (score 0):

I followed some comments and succesfully installed Ubuntu16.04 with [Rufus USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

But when I boot Ubuntu, it didn't display toolbar whish usually able to see at left.

The following commands helped me.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I also used these commands to enable gtx1080.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```